# Can I ask Firebird to use index (with like on strings) in left join condition on other column?

Tags: sql, firebird

I have table structures:

```
journal_entries (id integer, account varchar(20), doc_date, date, amount numeric(15,4))
selected_accounts (account varchar(20), selection_id integer)
```

I can query this and SQL used indexes both on doc_date and on account:

```
select je.*
  from journal_entries je
  where je.doc_date>='01.01.2022' and
        je.doc_date<='31.03.2022' and
        (je.account like '23%' or 
         je.account like '24%')
```

But when I am filling the selected_accounts table with data:

```
23%, 1
24%, 1
```

And I am trying to use condition in left join:

```
select
  from selected_accounts sa
    left join journal_entries je on (
      je.doc_date>='01.01.2022' and
      je.doc_date<='31.03.2022' and
      je.account like sa.account)
```

Then SQL is not using index on journal_entries.account data, it is using index on je.doc_date only.

Can I give some hints to optimizer or SQL engine that condition `je.account like sa.account` should use index on `je.account`?

I am using Firebird 3.1 and Firebird 2.1 but I guess, this issue is on other SQL databases as well.

I am gravitation towards the need to accept that I can not make optimal query with the condition in left join...

**Question supplemented:** I copied the plan (e.g. given by IBExpert) from the first query as the `plan` clause to the second query but the SQL engine reports:

```
 index <index on journal_entries.account> cannot be used in the specified plan
```

So, there is something in my query that prevents the reference and use of `journal_entries.account` index.

**Additional observation:** In fact - my database have 1M journal entries in 2022Q1 (period specified in my examples), then the first (good) query reports less than 1M indexed record reads, but the second (bad) query reports 2*1M indexed record reads (indexed beacuse of the index on `journal_entries.doc_date`), so, this is even worse than the full read by `doc_date` and then just filter by `selected_records` entries.

**One step forward:** Thanks to @Damien_The_Unbeliever comment I made this test (sic! first string prefixed with %):

```
select je.*
  from journal_entries je
  where je.doc_date>='01.01.2022' and
        je.doc_date<='31.03.2022' and
        (je.account like '%23%' or 
         je.account like '24%')
```

And no more the `je.account` index is used and the number of reads increased. So - it seems to me that Firebird query engine/optimizer scans that string literals used in `like` conditions and decides on the possibility to use index on `je.account`.

*So, maybe I can give some notice to Firebird (for my second/slow query) that I expect only post-%-fixed strings as `select_accounts.account output`? That would solve my issue in the case of Firebird engine.*

Comment: It's not `join` versus `where` that's making a difference. It's the fact that in the first instance, it can optimize the query based on knowing that both `like` expressions are *prefix* matches. In the second query it's got to accommodate *any* pattern that may appear in the table.

Comment: There is no Firebird 3.1, and if you're using Firebird 3.0.1, you really should update to 3.0.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to optimize `like` in this case, because Firebird cannot know what values your column has. The fact `somecolumn like '24%'` can use an index is because Firebird will *rewrite* that expression to `somecolumn starting with '24'` (see also [`LIKE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-commons-predlike), specifically the note titled *"About `LIKE` and the Optimizer"*). It is not possible to do so with parameters or values obtained from columns.

In other words, the obvious solution to your problem is to have `selected_accounts.account` not be populated with `'24%'`, but with `'24'`, and using [`STARTING WITH`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-commons-predstartwith) in your join condition.

In the case the wildcard doesn't always occur, and some times you need an exact match, you could use something like `je.account starting with replace(sa.account, '%', '') and je.account like sa.account`. This solution assumes that `%` only ever occurs as the last character, and there is no `_` wildcard used.